# pod install error on The `master` repo requires CocoaPods 0.32.1 but I am using CocoaPods 0.33.1

Tags: cocoapods

I just try to run very simple Podfile as follow

```
  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'  
  pod 'ObjectiveSugar', '~> 0.5'
```

But it will get follow error

```
[!] The `master` repo requires CocoaPods 0.32.1 -
Update CocoaPods, or checkout the appropriate tag in the repo.
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.4.0/lib/claide/command.rb:217:in `rescue in run': undefined     method `verbose?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.4.0/lib/claide/command.rb:210:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:51:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/bin/pod:24:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

But I have reinstall and double confirm (uninstall cocoapods and install again) to make sure.

```
gem list --local | grep cocoapods
cocoapods (0.33.1)
cocoapods-core (0.33.1)
cocoapods-downloader (0.6.1)
cocoapods-plugins (0.2.0)
cocoapods-trunk (0.1.3)
cocoapods-try (0.3.0)
```

Full verbose error log when I run second time as [here](https://gist.github.com/kkdai/f73e734bdf189ec0fc86), any idea or suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run `pod repo update`

If that doesn't work run `rm -rf ~/.cocoapods` and `pod setup`